# How to delete all the whitespace element in a list of string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a list of string,  `text= ['He', 'was', '' ,'sitting', ' ', 'next', ' ', 'to me']`

I want to delete the **whitespace** element **' '** from the list.

I tried using the filter method, but it only remove the empty elements,

```
list(filter(None, text))
```

I want the list to be like

```
['He', 'was' ,'sitting','next','to me']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost correct, you just used a wrong predicate:

```
list(filter(str.strip, text))
#['He', 'was', 'sitting', 'next', 'to me']
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, as you correctly pointed out, `list(filter(None, text))` is removing the empty strings, and not strings with whitespaces

To remove strings with whitespaces, you can [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the whitespaces from each element of the list and the do the comparison, and then make a new list with non-empty strings

```
text= ['He', 'was', '' ,'sitting', ' ', 'next', ' ', 'to me']

print([item for item in text if item.strip()])

#Or using filter
#print(list(filter(lambda item:item.strip(), text)))
```

The output will be

```
['He', 'was', 'sitting', 'next', 'to me']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe we can do like this much faster

```
text= ['He', 'was', '' ,'sitting', ' ', 'next', ' ', 'to me']
print(' '.join(text).split()) # this will remove both whitespace element + whitespaces

OUTPUT:
['He', 'was', 'sitting', 'next', 'to', 'me']
```